# how to create a proper geom_boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to create a regular boxplot chart, but am getting a weird dotted chart instead.

Could you please point out to me what I am doing wrong and how I can correct it?

Thank you very much.

```
box_plot <- comb_rpt %>% 
filter(!is.na(oracle_contract_desc.x), 
     service_mnth %in% c('2018-01', '2018-02', '2018-03', '2018-04',
                         '2018-05', '2018-06', '2018-07')) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x = service_mnth, y = var_est_to_actual)) +
geom_boxplot()
```

My Weird Boxplot looks like a dot:

[image: img]

Correct Boxplot looks like an actual box, with color fill

[image: img]

Comment: Can you make the problem reproducible and add `comb_rpt` to your question? Use `dput(comb_rpt)`, thanks.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing your data, but it looks like your boxplots are correct, but because you have very high and low outliers that are expanding the scale of your plot, the boxes are so compressed as to be difficult to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you've got a lot of `0`s in `var_est_to_actual` per `service_mnth`.

Let's reproduce the "issue".

First off, we generate data from a wide normal and show the boxplots.

```
set.seed(2018)
df <- setNames(data.frame(
    rnorm(100, sd = 100),
    rnorm(100, sd = 100)), c("2018-01", "2018-02"))    

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    gather(service_mnth, var_est_to_actual) %>%
    ggplot(aes(service_mnth, var_est_to_actual)) +
    geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

We now replace 70% of the observations per `service_mnth` with `0`s, and show the boxplot again for the revised data.

```
df %>%
    gather(service_mnth, var_est_to_actual) %>%
    group_by(service_mnth) %>%
    mutate(frac = (1:n()) / n()) %>%
    mutate(var_est_to_actual = if_else(frac < 0.7, 0, var_est_to_actual)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(service_mnth, var_est_to_actual)) +
    geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Notice the similarity with the boxplot you're showing.